# C# abstraction and generics in custom collections

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I have some unclarity over C# generics and abstraction.
I have a an abstract class AbstList which is inherited by Classes containig list of AbstRec

```
public abstract class AbstList<T> : IList<T> where T:AbstRec {...}
public class List1 : AbstList<Rec1> {}
public class List2 : AbstList<Rec2> {}
```

Each class List has a collection of elements of Rec, they inherit from AbsRec

```
public abstract class AbstRec {...}
public class Rec1 : AbstDb {...}
public class Rec2 : AbstDb {...}
```

I want to add a reference to parent to each class Rec, parent would be class inherited from AbstList. How do I achieve it? So far I was only able to find how to implement parent to class List, but Im not sure how to properly declare and pass the parent in AbstRec.

this does not work :( (the best overloaded method has some invalid arguments in Public Rec1)

```
public abstract class AbstRec 
{
    AbstList<AbstRec> parent;
    Public AbstRec(AbstList<AbstRec> parent)
    {
        this.parent=parent;
    }
}   

public  class Rec1 : AbstRec
{    
    Public Rec1(AbstList<Rec1> parent) : base(parent)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post a question, you should never simply say "this does not work". You should describe the behavior you are getting. If it is failing to build, you should copy and past the build error message.

Comment: Are you saying base(parent) does not set the parent property in the abstract class?

Comment: yes, I just edited it to make it clear

Comment: You cannot implicitly cast elements of a list to parent type. Please use generic variant interfaces if possible or handle casting.

Comment: have you check for Variance issues?

Comment: how do I use generic variant interface here? thanks

Comment: Your abstract class needs to become an interface, and mark `T` with `out` to make it covariant. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx for more information. This whole use case is *weird* though. Why would a class know about its container?

Comment: I found it convenient to have the reference: I intend to store some List related properties within the list (such as file location) and   thought that having a refrence to parent (=List) in Rec is a good thing to do. Thanks for the tip!